# Check for multiple text items in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a table I'm testing that the column headers are correct. The problem is `.contains()` only ever returns one element.

I can repeat the code for each instance, but it seems quite verbose. Feel I must be missing something in Cypress commands that can do this better.

```js
cy.get('th').eq(0).contains('Batman')
cy.get('th').eq(1).contains('Robin')
cy.get('th').eq(1).contains('The Flash')
/// etc
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Superheros and sidekicks</caption>
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col span="2" class="batman">
        <col span="2" class="flash">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <th scope="col">Batman</th>
        <th scope="col">Robin</th>
        <th scope="col">The Flash</th>
        <th scope="col">Kid Flash</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Skill</th>
        <td>Smarts</td>
        <td>Dex, acrobat</td>
        <td>Super speed</td>
        <td>Super speed</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tidy up the test by mapping elements to inner texts.

Note, specify the first row with `tr:eq(0)`

```js
const expectedHeaders = ['Batman', 'Robin', 'The Flash', 'Kid Flash']
cy.get('tr:eq(0) th')
  .then($th => [...$th].map(th => th.innerText))    // map to texts
  .should('deep.eq', expectedHeaders)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to select the row above, then use `.children()` to get a list of all the headers.

You can then chain multiple assertions about that list

```js
cy.get('tr').eq(0)                // row containing the heasers
  .children('th')                 // collection of header elements
  .should('contain', 'Batman')    // assert 1st text
  .and('contain', 'Robin')        // assert 2nd text
  .and('contain', 'The Flash')    // assert 3rd text
```

Answer (score 1):

If you store the expected in an array, you could use `.each()` to iterate through each `th`.

```js
const expected = ['Batman', 'Robin', 'Flash', 'Kid Flash']
cy.get('tr').eq(0)
  .children('th')
  .each(($th, index) => {
    cy.wrap($th).should('have.text', expected[index]);
  });
```